# how to remove the comma in perl

Tags: csv, perl

I have this sample data I wanted to remove the comma particularly the last comma of the line, btw it's .csv file.

```
W, S, Vbd2OX/NW, Vbd2OX/PW, Vbd3OX/NW, Vbd3OX/PW, 
ID,ID, 11200, V 11200, V 11200, V 11200, 
6,1,0.69,5.56,-5.56,10.5,-10.12,
6,2,3.99,7,-5.13,-7,640.455,
```

this 2 code is not working the last comma is still there

```
$line =~ s/\,$//g;
```

and

```
$line =~ s/,//g;
```

Comment: This appears to be CSV data so you may want to use a CSV parser/writer to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or other variation of code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    $line =~ s/\,\s*$//;
    print "$line\n";
}

__DATA__
W, S, Vbd2OX/NW, Vbd2OX/PW, Vbd3OX/NW, Vbd3OX/PW, 
ID,ID, 11200, V 11200, V 11200, V 11200, 
6,1,0.69,5.56,-5.56,10.5,-10.12,
6,2,3.99,7,-5.13,-7,640.455,
```

Answer (score 6):

If there are spaces after the last comma (which seems to be true for a couple of your lines), you need to:

```
s/, *$//;
```

No need to backslash-escape a comma; no need for `/g` when you want the substitution to happen at most once per line.

Comment: `s/,\s*$//` for a more lenient trailing comma stripping.

Comment: @tadman that would also remove a newline, bit only when there is a trailing comma, which seemed problematic

Comment: @kayegabato: But you've accepted the one that doesn't explain anything, this one does explain!

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for provided set of data

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while( <DATA> ) {
    /(.+)\,\s*/;
    print "$1\n";
}

__DATA__
W, S, Vbd2OX/NW, Vbd2OX/PW, Vbd3OX/NW, Vbd3OX/PW, 
ID,ID, 11200, V 11200, V 11200, V 11200, 
6,1,0.69,5.56,-5.56,10.5,-10.12,
6,2,3.99,7,-5.13,-7,640.455,
```